# how to sort items in a list alphabetically by the letters in their respective names.

Tags: python

I am trying to sort values in a list by the letters in their name: I want, for example,  ["8a", "8c", "8b", "8d"] to become ["8a", "8b","8c", "8d"]. Does this have something to do with a key?

Comment: This is very broad, and it's very likely this is not your real case, otherwise `sorted(lst)` will do it.

Comment: Will the letter always be the second character?

Comment: 1) What should the result be for a list like this: ['9a', '6b', '3d']? 2) Is the format of the entries in the list always one number followed by one character?

Comment: @Sean: Since you haven't  replied to @gowrath's clarification, I have added an answer based on `sort values in a list by the letters in their name` i.e any order of `letters` in string

Answer (score 3):

The answer is easy if the data looks like in your question. If the data is more complex you will have to give the `sort` method a key which contains only characters from the alphabet.

```
data =  ["34b", "2a5t", "2a5s", "abcd"]
data.sort(key=lambda x: ''.join(c for c in x if c.isalpha()))
print(data)
```

This will give you `['abcd', '2a5s', '2a5t', '34b']`.

If you want to see how the constructed key looks like you can check it like this:

```
for value in data:
    print(value, ''.join(c for c in value if c.isalpha()))

34b b
2a5t at
2a5s as
abcd abcd
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your format is always number followed by letter, you need to give the sort method a specific key to sort by: in this case you want to sort by the last character. A lot of the other answers are just sorting your list alphabetically using the number followed by letter whereas I get the feeling you only want to sort by the letter. This is one possible way:

```
 s = ['9d', '12a', '1e']
 sorted_s = sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[-1])   # sorts by the last character of every entry
```

This will return:

```
['12a', '9d', '1e']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by sorting it by a list.

```
list = ["8a", "8c", "8b", "8d"] 
list.sort()
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

That would solve solve your problem:

```
_list = ["8a", "8c", "8b", "8d"] 
_list.sort()
print _list
```

Output:

```
['8a', '8b', '8c', '8d']
```

Answer (score 0):

The .sort() method for lists has been mentioned; there's a sorting function that takes the list as an argument, and returns a sorted list without modifying the list in place:

```
>>> mylist = ["8a", "8c", "8b", "8d"]
>>> sorted(list)
['8a', '8b', '8c', '8d']
>>> mylist
['8a', '8c', '8b', '8d']
```

Comment: corrected, thanks. Keeping the variable name "list" simply because that's what OP called it.

Answer (score 0):

> trying to sort values in a list by the letters in their name

The example you mentioned is very simple. Based on your requirement, below is the code using `re.findall()` and `sorted()` to sort based on letters in any order within string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ['a9d', '1a2ba', '1e2s', '1b3tr']
>>> sorted(s, key=lambda x: re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", x))
['1a2ba', 'a9d', '1b3tr', '1e2s']  # Sorted based on: aba, ad, btr, es
```